# Code igniter Session is not storing data, it only saves the Email which we are entering in input box at login-form?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, session

Code-igniter Session is not storing data, it only saves the Email which we are entering in input box in login-form. I set this  $config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;  and created a ci_sessions table also in DB but no sake. I tried this on both versions on code-igniters(2 & 3)  Please help me to sort out this problem. Thank you. This is my code.  First one is controller and the second one is model.

```
public function validate_credentials()
{       
    $this->load->model('passenger_login_model');
    $query = $this->passenger_login_model->validate();

    if($query)
    {
        $data = array(
            'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'),
            'is_logged_in' => true,

             'P_ID' => $query->P_ID,
             'CNIC' => $query->CNIC
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        echo $this->session->userdata('Email'); 
        echo $this->session->userdata('P_ID');
        //redirect('front');
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Incorrect Email or Password!');</script>";
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

and as output, it only shows me the user@user.com not P_ID

and this is model

```
    class Passenger_Login_model extends CI_Model 
    {
/*`passenger`(`P_ID`, `Name`, `Image`, `CNIC`, `Passport_No`, `Gender`, `Email`, 
    `Password`, `Phone_No`, `Mob_No`, `Address_1`, `Address_2`, `Date` */
function validate()
{
    $data=array(
                'Email' =>$this->input->post('Email'),
                'Password' =>$this->input->post('Password')
                );
    $rec=$this->db->get_where('passenger', $data)->result();
    $c = count($rec);
    if($c>0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }   
}
function is_logged_in()
{
    $this->load->library('session');
    $is_logged_in = $this->session->userdata('is_logged_in');
    if(!isset($is_logged_in) || $is_logged_in != true)
    {
        echo 'You don\'t have permission to access this page.'.anchor('login',"Login"); 
        die();          
    }       
}}
```

Comment: Your validate() method is just returning TRUE or FALSE, so calling $query->P_ID and $query->CNIC won't work.  That's why there's no session data for those.

Comment: Dear Versalle, then what should i do? Please !

Comment: i change the validate functions, then it always giving me this error that Invalid email or password... My updated validate funcyion is ::  *****
    
   
  $query = $this->db->get('passenger');
  if ($query->num_rows == 1) 
  {
   return true;    
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return the data fetch from your model query, use fetch function to do that, for more reference [click](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#select), So your model validate function should be

```
function validate()
{
    $data=array(
                'Email' =>$this->input->post('Email'),
                'Password' =>$this->input->post('Password')
                );
    $rec=$this->db->get_where('passenger', $data);
    return $rec->result_array(); // returns data as array // might help you
}
```

return $res->result_array(); will return multipdimentional array of data from db, to know more about result_array() [check this](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Session issue is from your controller function the result is array now.

```
 public function validate_credentials()
    {       
        $this->load->model('passenger_login_model');
        $result_data = $this->passenger_login_model->validate(); 
    // result data is array now
        if(is_array($result_data) && count($result_data) > 0)
        {
        // var_dump($result_data); // check this var_dump you will get multidimensional array
        $data = array(
            'Email' => $this->input->post('Email'),
            'is_logged_in' => true,

             'P_ID' => $result_data[0]['P_ID'],
             'CNIC' => $result_data[0]['CNIC']
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        echo $this->session->userdata('Email'); 
        echo $this->session->userdata('P_ID');
        //redirect('front');
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "<script>alert('Incorrect Email or Password!');</script>";
        $this->index();
    }
}
```

Hope this help, Happy coding.

Comment: it give me the error 
Fatal error: Call to a member function result() on a non-object in E:\xampp\htdocs\img_new\application\models\passenger_login_model.php on line 36

Comment: @hamzajaved i missed out to check this line, result() function is already called from $rec=$this->db->get_where('passenger', $data)->result(); I have updated the answer, will help you

Comment: I doesn't watched that, my error isn't solved yet.. .Session is storing only the first record record of table... Please help me ??

Comment: @HamzaJaved updated my answer with result_array() to get array of data from query, that might help you

Comment: Can i ask one more question @keviveks, its not about session.

Comment: Yeah you can ask, and if this answer works, make it accept answer

Comment: Sir i have two tables.. (i-e) *(1) fare`(`Fare_ID`, `Flight_ID`, `Departure_Arrival_Station`, `Fare  and *(2) flights`(`Flight_ID`, `Flight_Name`, `No_Of_Seats.... I have foreach all data from fare table and it gives me Flight_ID, which is correct. How should i will get that flight_Name instead of Flight_ID on the screen.. I try on it, i'm showing you my code in next comment.

Comment: > getflightNames functionin model:

function getFlightName()
 {
     $this->db->select("flights.Flight_ID, flights.Flight_Name");
     $this->db->from('flights');
     $this->db->join('fare', 'fare.Flight_ID = flights.Flight_ID');
     $query = $this->db->get();
     return $query->result();
  }
> fare function in controller
    
    public function fare()
 {
  $data['tt'] = $this->db->get('fare')->result();
  $this->load->model('time_tbl_model');
  $data['flt_nm'] = $this->time_tbl_model->getFlightName();
  $this->load->view('front/fare', $data);
 }

>  and view is in next comment....

Comment: @HamzaJaved Stack Overflow has its own rules to follow, you current question in this page has answered, if you have any other issue make it as a new question, so that professionals can answer you exact question

Comment: >  The view
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($tt as $s): ?>
        <tr class="odd gradeX">
             <td><?php echo $s->Fare_ID; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $s->Flight_ID; ?></td>
             <?php foreach ($flt_nm as $ff): ?>
                <td><?php echo $ff->Flight_Name; ?> </td>
             <?php endforeach; ?>
             <td><?php echo $s->Departure_Arrival_Station; ?></td>
             <td><?php echo $s->Fare; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tbody>

Please sir, I will be very thankful to you

Comment: @HamzaJaved make it as a new question as i mentioned in the above comment

Comment: OK sir.. I am posting it as a new question

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved, i just updated the model to this...

```
function validate()
{
    $data=array(
                'Email' =>$this->input->post('Email'),
                'Password' =>$this->input->post('Password')
                );
    $query = $this->db->get('passenger');
    if ($query->num_rows()) 
    {
        return $query->row();               
    }   
 }
```

Comment: I doesn't watched that, my error isn't solved yet.. .Session is storing only the first record record of table... Please help me ??